# How do I save a Plugin's date settings-field?

Tags: plugin-development, datetime, settings

I've got a plugin with some custom settings, like this:

```php
protected function defineSettings()
{
    return array(
                 'serviceendpoint' => array(AttributeType::String, 'required'=>true),
                 'passkey' => array(AttributeType::String, 'required'=>true),
                 'newregistrationdate' => array(AttributeType::DateTime, 'required'=>false),
                 );
}
```

Then I have a _settings template, which renders the form:

```
{{ forms.textField({
    first:        true,
    label:        "CRM Endpoint URL"|t,
    id:           'serviceendpoint',
    name:         'serviceendpoint',
    instructions: "The URL for the CRM service ."|t,
    value:        settings.serviceendpoint,
    autofocus:    true,
    placeholder: "https://example.com/api/...",
    errors:       settings.getErrors('serviceendpoint')
}) }}

{{ forms.textField({
    label:        "The service passkey"|t,
    id:           'passkey',
    name:         'passkey',
    instructions: ""|t,
    value:        settings.passkey,
    placeholder: "1234...",
    errors:       settings.getErrors('passkey')
}) }}

<pre>Val: "{{ dump(settings.newregistrationdate) }}"</pre>
{{ forms.dateField({
    label:        "New registrations after this date"|t,
    id:           'newregistrationdate',
    name:         'newregistrationdate',
    instructions: "Users registered after this date will get a welcome email"|t,
    value:        settings.newregistrationdate.date|default,
    errors:       settings.getErrors('newregistrationdate')
}) }}
```

The String-typed values are saved just fine. But the `DateTime` always comes back as `false`.

I've tried adding a prepSettings function, and doing:

```
 $settings['newregistrationdate'] = new DateTime($settings['newregistrationdate']['date']);
```

but it makes no difference.

What does `prepSettings` have to return for `DateTime` typed fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, you need to use `AttributeType::Mixed` as Justin Kimbrell suggests. The date will then be escaped and stored in the database like this: *

`{"newregistrationdate":{"date":"2\/1\/2015"}}`

Now, the dateField in your settings template will expect a `DateTime` object for its value – so just passing `getSettings()` as is will make it choke. You can get around that by adding the following to the `getSettingsHtml()` method:

```
$settings = $this->getSettings();
if ( isset( $settings[ 'newregistrationdate' ][ 'date' ] ) ) {
    $settings[ 'newregistrationdate' ] = new DateTime( $settings[ 'newregistrationdate' ][ 'date' ] );
}
return craft()->templates->render( 'yourPluginHandle/settings', array(
    'settings' => $settings,
) );
```

...and then finally, make sure the `dateField` constructor looks in the right place for its value by removing the `date` key of the `settings.newregistrationdate` property:

```
{{ forms.dateField({
    label:        "New registrations after this date"|t,
    id:           'newregistrationdate',
    name:         'newregistrationdate',
    instructions: "Users registered after this date will get a welcome email"|t,
    value:        settings.newregistrationdate,
    errors:       settings.getErrors('newregistrationdate')
 }) }}
```

Solution is tested.

- Note that the date object is actually serialized, escaped and stored properly even if you use `AttributeType::DateTime`, however `getSettings()` will always return the attribute value as `false`. Could be a bug?

Comment: Mats thanks for your answer, for field types I use Craft's `DateTime::createFromString` helper function (following [Brandon's how-to](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4289/125)). Any idea why I don't get this to work for my plugin settings? I use the function in both, `prepSettings` and `getSettingsHtml`. The data gets saved in array format including timezone etc. and not in "2015-02-24 10:23:00" format as for all other datetime data I have. Any ideas?

Comment: carlcs, I don't really know, sorry.

Like Justin Kimbrell points out, it looks like the settings model can't handle the serialized DateTime, so it returns `false`. The only thing I've been able to store _and_ retrieve is a plain old serialized array (using `AttributeType::Mixed`). Would be interesting to hear the Craft guys chime in, whether this is a bug or if there's a way around it.

As for the `DateTime::createFromString` helper, in the OP's case it doesn't really matter which is used, that or `new DateTime()` – although I guess the former is best practice.

Comment: FWIW, this has been fixed in Craft 3 and probably won't be [officially fixed](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/9078/57) in the 2.x branch.

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff No worries!

Comment: Thanks for this @mmikkel - so useful! I had one extra wrinkle - the dates entered in my forms are dd/mm/yyyy which `DateTime()` complains about. So I had to do `new DateTime( str_replace('/', '-', $settings['newregistrationdate']['date']) )`. I imagine this is locale dependent. If your site's multilingual, then users can change their locale in 'My Account' which may complicate things further - each user submitting dates in different formats?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't have time to setup this scenario locally, but you may want to use AttributeType::Mixed. I believe the dateField macro returns the value as an array, so using AttributeType::Mixed should allow that value to be saved. All your other code looks correct, so it has to be your settings model not getting populated correctly.