# Repopulate dateTime field in plugin settings page

Tags: plugin-development, datetime, validation

In my plugin settings page, I have a startDate input which is a dateTime field.

**_settings.html**

```
{{
    forms.dateField({
     'label': 'Start Date'|t,
     'instructions': 'Choose a date'|t,
     'id': 'myStartDate',
     'name': 'myStartDate',
     'placeholder': 'mm/dd/yyyy',
     'value': settings.myStartDate,
     'errors': settings.getErrors('myStartDate')
    })
}}
```

My data is getting saved correctly - I can see it:

**json**

```
  ....
"myStartDate": {
    "date": "2015-04-13 05:00:00
}
  ....
```

So I thought cool. I just need: `myStartDate.date` and all is well. No luck.

What is curious to me, is when I fill out my start date, but my form fails validation, the date that I have entered is correctly repopulated. I don't have to re-enter the date.

But, once I successfully submit my settings, and then come back, my date field is no longer populated.

I've tried `myStartDate` and `myStartDate.date` and `myStartDate|date("m/d/Y")` but all with no luck.

I feel like I'm abusing this community with so many questions lately. I know the dateTime field needs to be a dateTime object - and I assume that's why it's not working for me. I'm not passing it what it needs.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: No worries about "abusing" – this site is in beta and needs all the questions it can get, and this is a legitimate one. There seems to be some issues with how the plugin's settings model retrieves DateTime objects from the database – [see this thread](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/8358/1098) for a workaround.

Comment: Well, I feel slightly better now, I did read through the post you linked to prior to posting my question and I thought to myself - surely this isn't what I need - it's got to be something I'm doing. At least I'm going down the right path(s) I suppose. 

Do you think it's "bug worthy" to bring up to the folks at Pixel and Tonic?

Thank you again!

Comment: I already sent Brad Bell a DM on Twitter asking him to check out the original thread, so hopefully he'll be able to shed some light on the matter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, this is a bug in Craft 2.x that's already been fixed in the Craft 3.x branch.

Considering there is a [workaround](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8348/how-do-i-save-a-plugins-date-settings-field/8358) for 2.x and the proper fix would be pretty ugly in 2, we're just going to let this one die a slow death with the release of Craft 3.